# How to pass custom array as a blob

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, k-means

I am trying to implement K-means clustering using python. I am following this tutorial https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.11-k-means.html

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
X, y_true = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=4,
                   cluster_std=0.60, random_state=0)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=50);
```

I have custom array `X=[0.6,0.7,0.32,0.54......0.87]`
How can I pass my custom array in the make_blobs function?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to make clustering on your X data instead of clustering the sample data generated with the function `make_blobs()`. (I cannot  ask in the comment as I dont have the reputation yet and that is why I answer directly)

If you want to cluster your own data with K-means then you should look here: [sklearn.cluster.KMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

First, you need to create a numpy array can create a numpy array:
`X=np.array([0.6,0.7,0.32,0.54......0.87])`

Then you can apply the KMeans fitting and prediction as shown in the following example:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0], [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [4, 4]])
```

If you want to plot your data then you can have a look to a more advanced example in order to plot [plot_cluster_iris](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html)